# Irreducibility of Polynomials over Residue Class Ring

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Given some polynomial $P \in \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}[T]$, is there an easy way to check if $P$ is irreducible? My understanding is that I cannot use Eisenstein's criterion because, in general, $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ is not a unique factorization domain.

Comment: You can consider the Berlekamp algorithm in the field with p elements, p prime.

Comment: Usually we want $K[T]$ with a field $K$. Here $K=\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$ is a field if and only if $m$ is prime.

Comment: @Fabrizio: that seems like what I was searching for, I will look into it. I guess I have to make do with the case where $m$ is prime.